# Chrome and local JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-jtable

I have a code like this: http://codepad.org/0j9m2Xdw

These files:

`<link href="js/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<script src="js/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

are in 100% in correct location. I run `google-chrome` with `--allow-file-access` and `--allow-file-access-from-files` parameters. Even that I still get a blank page when I try to access my `index.html` location, which is: `file:///home/myusername/code/web/index.html`

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you looked in the console in developer tools to see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: previously, a number of times,  I have had to clear the chrome cache. While I did not fully investigate; it seemed like a bug at the time.

Comment: Whoops, console from developer tools gives me these errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.jtable.min.js:53` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:15`. This is jTable 2.3.0.

Comment: @Teddy jtable is jquery plugin, so, first you need to include jquery

Comment: Okay, I have included jquery-2.0.2.min.js in my index.html and now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)} has no method 'widget' in jquery.jtable.min.js:25` and `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jtable' in index.html:17`... Sorry, I'm a novice to JS. Link to `index.html` with jquery included: http://ideone.com/q189nm

Answer (score 1):

JTable needs also jQueryUI, try this :

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- JqueryUI -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js  " type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
<link href="js/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxibaezpy/v37FF/) demo